# Can't call signalR server method from java client. is this possible?

Tags: java, signalr.client

I find this in official documentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3Tt.png)

Is it possible to somehow implement sending messages to the server (I use private socket server)?

I can't find any solutions for resolve this problem, all answers is very outdated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible to call the SignalR server method in Java, because SignalR is based on NET library, mainly used in Real time communication in the NET environment. Java and NET is two different programming languages and platforms, with limited interoperability between them. You can use methods such as HTTP or WebSocket to send requests or messages to communicate with the server.

Comment: I understand you, but when they implemented the same method in the Dart language, all these functions worked, it’s strange

Comment: Hi @Tolkin Please use this package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.signalr?view=aspnet-signalr-java

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. [There are 3 modes in azure signalr service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-resource-faq#what-is-the-meaning-of-the--default----serverless---and--classic--service-modes--how-can-i-choose-).

The tips you shared, it just tell us, if you are using `serverless` or `classic` mode to connect azure signalr, your java clients can't call the hub methods.

It depends on how you configure Azure Signalr Service in asp.net Core.

**Here is a sample for you.**

[hubConnection.send("BroadcastMessage", input);](https://github.com/fiodarsazanavets/SignalR-on-.NET-6---the-complete-guide/blob/60f66a3e73cde7cde4f21a6d8a5439c6ec052753/Chapter-04/Part-02/JavaClient/app/src/main/java/JavaClient/App.java#L23)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I’m sorry but I didn’t quite understand your answer. As I understand it, your answer is related to the Azure service, I have my own local network socket server, and the methods do not work send and invoke. I receive messages from the server but cannot send

Comment: Hi @Tolkin Is your local network socket server based on asp.net Core Signalr?

Comment: Hi, yes, now i get error  Failed to invoke 'SendMessage' due to an error on the server, but  on server nothing happened and it work when i use dart code, but when try it with java get error.

Comment: Or how do I need to configure the server for the Java client?

Comment: Hello @Tolkin, share me the method of  `SendMessage` inside of you hub, and share me your client  java code. I am familiar with how to troubleshoot the signalr issue.